# unexpectedly found nil tableView.registerNib

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, swift2

First of all, I did collapse tableview and everything is fine but when i drag button that make me navigate to another controller it give me error

**Note** that the button inside tableviewcell

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

this is my code

```
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tableData = [
        ["title": "Gender", "height": "118", "cellID": "cell1"],
        ["title": "Componnet", "height": "205", "cellID": "cell2"],
        ["title": "Lille Attribute", "height": "905", "cellID": "cell3"],
        ["title": "Sensory Effect", "height": "215", "cellID": "cell4"],
        ["title": "Emotional Messages", "height": "338", "cellID": "cell5"],
        ["title": "Personalities", "height": "336", "cellID": "cell6"],
        ["title": "Country", "height": "97", "cellID": "cell7"],
        ["title": "Season", "height": "94", "cellID": "cell8"]
    ]
    expandSections = NSMutableArray() as [AnyObject]
    for var i = 0; i < tableData.count; ++i {
        expandSections .append(false);
    }
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell1", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1") // in this line
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell2", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2")
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell3", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell3")
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell4", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell4")
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell5", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell5")
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell6", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell6")
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell7", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell7")
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell8", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell8")
```

Comment: how do u created the tableview , can you show once

Comment: did you register your nib?

Comment: i create it programmatically

Comment: @iamalizade , yes i did as you can see above

Comment: @AhmedSafadi try this: `tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "nibName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellID")`

Comment: @iamalizade , same problem fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

, it's loading for first time and work the problem come when it load the view controller again , it's like this nib is registered , you can't register it another time

Comment: @AhmedSafadi did you set in your nib an identifier? Check it again

Comment: @iamalizade you mean this http://i.imgur.com/h2LnrYe.png ?

Comment: yes, exactly! You passed it empty. Add `cell1` there

Comment: ok give me a sec let me try

Comment: same problem 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: note that this happened when i click on any button inside nib tableview cell that navigate me to another storyboard , if i drag button to the controller it works fine

Comment: I don't think it's register problem. Can you print the value of tableView. I guess that'll be nil.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your tableView is being declared as UITableView! and it's not initialized when the code you posted above gets executed. Make sure the tableView is not nil when you're registering the nibs. Adding the entire code would help a lot.